# Crystal Report on C#

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

Well I have a Cyrstal report which has 4 sub reports on and it is linked through an ItemID column and a Culture, so it has a parameter value "?Pm-ItemID" and "?Pm-Culture" now i'm using DataSet to load the data to the Crystal Report's datasource, when I run the report its giving me an error which was an asking parameter field was not suplied, so i think my question would be what am I going to pass to those ParameterFields?

here's an idea.

```
ReportDocument myreport = new ReportDocument();
myreport.Load("C:\MyReport.rpt");
DataSet ds = GenerateReportData();
myreport.SetDataSource(ds);

//Loop through each to Load the DataSet
for (int i = 0; i < myreport.Subreports.Count; i++)
{
    ReportDocument subreport = myreport.SubReports[i];
    DataSet subds = GenerateReportData(subreport.name)
    subreport.SetDataSource(subds);
}

//I can see that there's a parameterfields in myreport.ParameterFields
//As I look through inside it there are 8 ParameterFields repeating Pm-ItemID and Pm-Culture
foreach (ParameterField pf in myreport.ParameterFields)
{
    myreport.SetParameterValue(pf.Name, Value???);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I see what's wrong.

```
ReportDocument subreport = myreport.SubReports[i];
DataSet subds = GenerateReportData(subreport.name)
subreport.SetDataSource(subds);
```

should not be done this way, it should be

```
DataSet subds = GenerateReportData(subreport.name)
myreport.SubReports[i].SetDataSource(subds);
```

Comment: I forgot this is a com object, which might not support oop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Crystal, but in SSRS it works like this:

1) create a subreport and create some parameters

2) create the main report, put there the subreport and in the properties you can specify what to bind to the subreport's parameters

Conclusion: I don't think this is supposed to be set in code, rather report designer.

Comment: it is set in the report designer, it is linked MainItemReport.ItemID linked to SubItemReport.ItemID and so on, but as the report run it's asking for the value of ?Pm-ItemID and ?Pm-Culture

Comment: as you can see, I thought setting the data set through each subreports was sufficient, notice the foor loop, but as it goes along, i got an error that some parameter fields where it has no value.